# Specifying specific column and traversing all the rows in that column in python using pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am traversing through different Excel sheets with the same format (using the pandas library in python). The main thing I am trying to do is store the numerical values in the row 'Invoice Number', I just wrote X's to simplify it. I am unsure how I would go about this, while it seems simple I can't seem to get the proper loop (new to python but experience with programming in another language). Example of the excel sheet layout:

```
Invoices
Payment Number    Invoice Number   Invoice Date Description   Invoice Amount
   x                    x                  x                       x 
   x                    x                  x                       x
   x                    x                  x                       x
   x                    x                  x                       x
```

What I'm thinking is something like (pseudocode):

```
df = pd.read_excel('Excel.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
for columns in df:
   if(columns == 'Invoice Number):
      values[columns] = df[columns]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: So you want to traverse through all the sheets and store all the values in the column 'Invoice Number' in each sheet?

Comment: Can you show example of output you need? You want to store numerical value in column 'invoice number' but from where you are getting this values? If possible please explain everything in detail.

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal Just this specific sheet, once it works for this i know how i can go about doing it for every sheet that i open up. I just want to store the values that are in the Invoice Number so yes you are correct

Comment: @Nihilist I want to store the numerical values that come from the Invoice Number column, there is already values in the excel sheet (I just wrote x to represent some numerical value). I just want to traverse the excel sheet and store the values that are in that column specifically into an array, there is no specific output im looking for. I will do more with the data from there!

Comment: You can just do to convert invoice number column to horizontal, is that what you mean by traverse? If yes then you can do this by `df_traversed = df['Invoice Number'].T`

Comment: if you want to store in array you can do `list(df['Invoice Number'])`